# Retrieving Information associated with IAP Product Registered on iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've created an eBook player application which has books that need to be sold under In-App-Purchase. These books i've added as Non-Consumable Product's under my application in iTunes Connect. While registering the Product's i've uploaded a SCREENSHOT for every product. I want to download this Screen Shot uploaded against each product into my application while showing the In-App-Book-Store to user. I've gone through the Store Kit Programming guide & didn't find a way to retrieve the screenshot's associated with product's.

Is this possible? If so, then how do i go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no API for retrieving screenshots in-app. The in-app purchase screenshots are designed to help app reviewers understand how to find the item.

The easiest thing to do would be to package the screenshots with the app. You could name them with the product ID to make them easy to match. You could also make them available at a URL:

```
NSString *productId = @"my.app.product.one";
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", productId];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
if (image == nil) {
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someserver.com/productImages/%@", imageName]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```